# Docker Python request module not working with specific broadband provider

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, python-requests, connection-timeout

```
import requests
requests.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon')
```

I am facing strange problem in docker-compose python request module.

I change my internet provider recently from then in docker container python pip and request module not work. It raise the following error:

```
ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pokeapi.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/pokemon (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7c784757b0>, 'Connection to pokeapi.co timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
```

If i change to mobile data then it works again. What will be the issue?

Comment: you need to troubleshoot your router/provider, for example firewall rules and so on. initially I suggest to try to trace route this address from your PC from both mobile and home network and then with results go support ticket request to your provider. and ask why it differ (if it is)